# SQL Query: Display only latest Id from each set

Tags: c#, sql, linq, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following SQL Table:

```
Name       Description   Id   UserId   CreatedDate
UserSet1   Desc1         1    Abc      06/01/2018
UserSet1   Desc2         2    Def      06/02/2018
UserSet2   Desc for 2    5    NewUser  06/04/2018
UserSet2   Desc for 2    7    NewUser  06/19/2018
```

What I want to extract from the above table is just the latest Id for each Name so that I could get the following output

```
Name      Description    Id    UserId    CreatedDate
UserSet1  Desc2          2     Def       06/01/2018
UserSet2  Desc for 2     7     NewUser   06/19/2018
```

Since Id 2 & 7 are the latest entries in the table for UserSet1 & UserSet2, I would like to display that instead of all the entries in the table.

Any inputs how can I get the desired result.

I am open for solutions directly returning the output or any linq (C#) solutions as well. Ie returning the entire dataset and then using linq to filter the above.

Comment: You can use window functions.

Comment: If you have access to SQL, you could just GROUP BY `Name` and SELECT TOP 1 `Id`

Comment: What version and flavor of SQL?

Comment: I am actually using Dynamo DB from AWS. Sorry for this as it is the first time I am using dynamo db. Now that I think of it being a no sql database, this would be possible only filtering out results in code once we get the entire results back from the DB.

Comment: Will DynamoDB allow you to `SELECT` columns that aren't included in the `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Also, by "latest ID", do you mean the highest number `ID` or the `ID` on the record with the most recent `CreatedDate`?

Comment: @Shawn, I am looking for highest number ID. Also I am now looking for Linq  solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Since you are looking for the highest number ID, the `GROUP BY` method would probably be easier to work with.

Using a window function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Name, Description, Id, UserId, CreatedDate
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM myTable
) s1
WHERE rn = 1
```

I don't have an instance of dynamoDB to test on, but I believe it can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function.

Comment: You may also want to create a `view` in your database and just query that `view` instead. That way you aren't trying to build the needed results in Linq.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for pointing to right direction. I have got this working with the below code of Linq and C#:

```
 var results = response.GroupBy(row => row.Name)
                   .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(row => row.Id).Take(1));
```

For the initial tests this seems to be working. Let me know if you think this has come issues.

Comment: Just one thing here is that I want to add another condition to this.  Along with the result set obtained above I also want the result to show all ID's that have ID as 0. So my result set would contain ID 2, 7 and 0. Any inputs to how can I modify the above Linq?

Answer (score 0):

This should be a general SQL answer:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable Y1
WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id)
              FROM yourtable Y2
             WHERE Y2.Name = Y1.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was MS SQL you could use Partition By command, otherwise most performant way would be:

```
select * from Table
where Id in (
    select Max(Id) from Table
    Group By Name
)
```

not sure if you can leave Name out of the Select statement, you might need to do:

```
select * from Table
where Id in (
    Select Id from 
        (select Name, Max(Id) as Id from Table
        Group By Name)
)
```

Comment: RE: MS SQL Performance >> I don't think the optimizer will be more performant for an `IN` clause vs a `PARTITION BY` clause. An `IN (1,2,3,...)` is essentially short for `WHERE Id = 1 or Id = 2 OR Id = 3 OR ...`. For a large subquery, it can get to be a very complex statement. A `PARTITION BY` is still set-based.

Comment: @user007, do you know how can write the same with LINQ for C#

Comment: @Shawn Regarding performance I was thinking about correlated subquery as I can see some people have their solution with.