# Linq: Adding extra condition along with GroupBy and SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq

Continuing from my previous post:
[SQL Query: Display only latest Id from each set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50860944/sql-query-display-only-latest-id-from-each-set)

I have the following SQL Table:

```
Name       Description   Id   UserId   CreatedDate

UserSet1   Desc1         0    Abc      06/01/2018
UserSet1   Desc2         1    Abc      06/01/2018
UserSet1   Desc4         2    Def      06/02/2018
UserSet2   Desc for 2    5    NewUser  06/04/2018
UserSet2   Desc for 2    7    NewUser  06/19/2018
```

What I want to extract from the above table is just the latest Id for each Name so that I could get the following output

```
Name      Description    Id    UserId    CreatedDate

UserSet1  Desc1          0     Def       06/01/2018
UserSet1  Desc2          2     Def       06/01/2018
UserSet2  Desc for 2     7     NewUser   06/19/2018
```

Since Id 2 & 7 are the latest entries in the table for UserSet1 & UserSet2, I would like to display that instead of all the entries in the table. Now this was solved with the below LINQ code. Now I have another requirement to also show all rows which have ID's zero as well (see above expected result).

```
var results = response
  .GroupBy(row => row.Name)
  .SelectMany(g => g
     .OrderByDescending(row => row.Id)
     .Take(1));
```

How can I modify my above Linq so that it shows all highest no IDs of the name together with any ID's which are zero as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var results = response.GroupBy(row => row.Name)
                        .SelectMany(g => g
                        .OrderByDescending(row => row.Id)
                        .Take(1))
                      .Union(response.Where(x=>x.Id== 0));
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. I was missing Union statement.